# running tasks on an sbt build

Tags: scala, sbt

I have just started using `sbt` and am not too sure exactly how it works, I have created a task in the `build.sbt` file

```
lazy val execScript = taskKey[Unit]("Execute the shell script")
execScript := {
"C:/Users/dsweeney/Documents/configuration-services/swagger/codegen/SwaggerActivate.bat" !
}
```

I can run it fine but I want it to run every time the build file is run, how exactly do I do this?

I have been trying to add it to the `.aggerate` method

```
lazy val root = Project(
 id = "configsvcs",
 base = file(".")
).dependsOn(data_model)
.aggregate(data_model, slickMigration, execScript )
```

but that doesn't appear to be working error is Too many arguments for method aggregate.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to generate source files during your build. The correct way to achieve this is:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += execScript.taskValue
```

This will run the task every time before compiling your project. For this to work, your task must return a list of files it generates:

```
lazy val execScript = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Execute the shell script")

execScript := {
   val outputDir := sourceManaged.in(Compile).value / "generated"

   // bad: absolute local path
   "C:/Users/dsweeney/Documents/configuration-services/swagger/codegen/SwaggerActivate.bat" !

   // return all Java files of the output directory
   outputDir ** "*.java" // or "*.scala"?
}
```

Note, it is good practice to generate the files into the `sourceManaged` directory.